# How to run multiple grid searches with H2O

Tags: h2o

I have an H2O frame X from which I extract 3 different H2O frames X1, X2, X2 (based on some filtering condition)

I want to run a grid search on X1 and get Model1, a grid search on X2 and get Model2..etc

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Are you filtering just columns, or both rows and columns?  Also, what API are you using (R, Python, etc?).

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create 3 different R or Python scripts that each create the Frame X_i and then run GridSearch_i on it, you can run all of them in parallel. If you're doing it in one script or interactively, then the grid searches will be sequential.

Comment: We use Scala, should just submit through different threads and it should work?